# How to replace value if is empty Jquery

Tags: jquery, magento

I have a question about jquery changing value on select from dropdown.

This jquery is based on magento Simple Configurable Product extension.

This is the source:

```
$childProducts[$productId]["productDate"] = $product->getAttributeText('preorderdate');
```

Return  `var spConfig = new Product.Config({"productDate":"","productDate":"November 2013"})`

Jquery to change div text on select.

```
Product.Config.prototype.updateProductDate = function(productId) {
    var productDate = this.config.productDate;
    if (productId && this.config.childProducts[productId].productDate) {
        productDate = this.config.childProducts[productId].productDate;
    }
// if(productDate.lenght === 0)
    if(productDate === ''){
    $$('p.availability.in-stock span').each(function(el) {
        el.innerHTML = 'Is in stock';
    })
    $$('p.availability.in-stock span').each(function(el) {
        el.innerHTML = productDate;
    });
};
```

The issue is that on select the option with no value is still showing the blank value and not returning `el.innerHTML = 'Is in stock';` .

Where is wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Found solution by myself, brackets not in your place.

```
 Product.Config.prototype.updateProductDate = function(productId) {
        var productDate = this.config.productDate;
        if (productId && this.config.childProducts[productId].productDate) {
            productDate = this.config.childProducts[productId].productDate;
        }
        $$('p.availability.in-stock span').each(function(el) {
        el.innerHTML = productDate;
        });
    if(productDate === ''){
     $$('p.availability.in-stock span').each(function(el) {
            el.innerHTML = 'This is in stock';
        });
}
};
```

Comment: I recommend you write up a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.  You shouldn't expect others to do your work for you, make it as easy as possible for them to answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping aside the problem where does you {  of if condition closed ??

```
 Product.Config.prototype.updateProductDate = function(productId) {
        var productDate = this.config.productDate;
        if (productId && this.config.childProducts[productId].productDate) {
            productDate = this.config.childProducts[productId].productDate;
        }
    // if(productDate.lenght === 0)
        if(productDate === ''){    //WHERE DOES THIS BRCKET CLOSED ??
        $$('p.availability.in-stock span').each(function(el) {
            el.innerHTML = 'Is in stock';
        })
        $$('p.availability.in-stock span').each(function(el) {
            el.innerHTML = productDate;
        });
    };
```

Comment: I found the bracket not closed, i close it, but still cannot change if value is empty.